# Add Snowflake calculated geography column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a block of data with lat/longs and I'm trying to add a point to a Snowflake table from this data.

First I tried to accomplish it when I created the table with:

```
create or replace table geo (
 best_lat double,
 best_lon double,
 geography geography as (ST_POINT(best_lon, best_lat)));
```

This errored out with `SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 2 Data type of virtual column does not match the data type of its expression for column 'GEOGRAPHY'. Expected data type 'GEOGRAPHY', found 'VARIANT'`

Then I tried to add the column with:

```
alter table geo
add column geom geography as (select st_makepoint(best_lon, best_lat) from geo)
```

This errored out with `SQL compilation error: Invalid virtual column expression [(SELECT ST_MAKEPOINT(GEO.BEST_LON, GEO.BEST_LAT) AS "ST_MAKEPOINT(BEST_LON, BEST_LAT)" FROM GEO AS GEO)]`

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake doesn’t really support calculated columns, what it does do is allow you to set a default value for a column and this default can be a simple SQL statement. The syntax is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters)

Because this isn’t a pure calculated column, you can still insert values directly into the column, which will override the defined default value.